# In excel, how do you group according to data range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm still a beginner when it comes to writing macros in excell, but I want to write a macro that takes values:

```
149,000 
136,000
100,000
100,000
75,000
50,000
50,000
35,000
25,000
26,000
25,500
25,000
```

And groups them like so:

```
**100,000 - 149,999**
149,000 
136,000
100,000
100,000

**50,000 - 99,999**
75,000
50,000
50,000

**25,000 - 49,999**
35,000
25,000
26,000
25,500
25,000
```

How would I go about accomplishing this? I've been playing around with =COUNTIF() but I'm struggling.

Comment: I think this might well belong on SuperUser SE.

Comment: @Silverfish: Isn't a macro a program of sorts?

Comment: @Scortchi The question can be solved with pivot tables, and the OP was wondering about =COUNTIF() - indeed, other formulas should work too - all of which strikes me as a better fit for SuperUser than SO. I note that teylyn (who knows both SuperUser and SO very well) has suggested the same thing below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Excel you can do this with a pivot table instead of a macro. Drag the values into the row area of the pivot panel, then right-click any value in the pivot and select Group. You can specify the start, end and the interval. The interval will be regular, though, not like your sample, where it's not.

[image]

Edit:

If the pivot grouping does not help, you can use a formula to calculate the group as a text value, then pivot on that text.

The formula is along the lines of

```
=LOOKUP([@Price],{0,25000,50000,10000,150000},{"< 25,000","25,000 - 49,999","50,000 - 999,999","100,000 - 149,999","> 150,000"})
```

[image]

Comment: The whole idea is to be able to open a .CSV of data exported from a database and simply use a macro in excel to group the values based on certain ranges.

Comment: I added an alternative. This question really belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: LOL. Marked as answer in March 2022, six and a half years after it was posted.